# cookies are not deleted when page close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]
i was create cookie (page load counting) whenever page load and then next delete cookies whenever close the window 
**my problem**: cookies are not deleted 

**mycode:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y3xs7/6

Edit: i remove expire date but no luck

Comment: Note: Session end is reached only when you close the browser. Closing the tab in which your page is loaded will not clear session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

write this code anywhere in script tag

```
window.onbeforeunload=clear_cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the cookie to expire after one month.

```
var futdate = new Date()
var expdate = futdate.getTime()
expdate += 3600000 * 24 *30  //expires in 1 hour (ed note: actually one MONTH)
futdate.setTime(expdate)

var newCookie="pageCount="+counter
newCookie += "; expires=" + futdate.toGMTString()
window.document.cookie=newCookie
```

Persistent cookies (those with specific expiration dates) are not deleted when the browser closes.

If you don't give the cookie an expiration date, it becomes a session cookie, which is deleted when the browser closes.

Also note that as of [Chrome 19](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1285134) and [Firefox 3](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443354), session cookies aren't deleted if the browser's startup mode option is "continue where I left off."

Comment: i remove expire date but no luck

Comment: @srini: As you see in the screenshot you added, there's now no expire date.  However, session cookies are deleted when the *browser* exits, not when the tab closes.